# How to use Wacom Intuos on Ubuntu 20.04 in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, wacom

I run Ubuntu 20.04 through Oracle VirtualBox. My Wacom tablet (Intuos CTL 6100) works perfectly on Windows. On Ubuntu, the pen is correctly detected and acts fine as a mouse, however I have the following issues:

- when trying to write on Xournal 0.4.8.2016 nothing happens, if I deactivate xinput it works poorly.
- small characters (especially if I try to draw letters) are not written in Xournal, I have a disk that pops each time I try to write something too small and slowly, as if the action was recognized as something else (click ?)
- similar issue on GIMP, only large lines are written
- the tablet does not seem to be recognized, when I type in the console `xsetwacom --list devices` nothing happens. This is weird considering the movement of the pen is correctly detected.

If I type `xinput` in the console I get this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox mouse integration              id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox USB Tablet                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

After following the recommendations to integrate USB in virtualbox, the new result when typing xinput becomes

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
VirtualBox mouse integration                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
VirtualBox USB Tablet                       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Wacom Intuos BT M Pen stylus                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Wacom Intuos BT M Pen eraser                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Wacom Intuos BT M Pen cursor                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Wacom Intuos BT M Pad pad                   id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
 Virtual core keyboard                      id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
 Virtual core XTEST keyboard                id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 Power Button                               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 Sleep Button                               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 Video Bus                                  id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 AT Translated Set 2 keyboard               id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The tablet now works properly, up to the (fairly annoying) fact that the pointer associated to the tablet is invisible.

Comment: This is a brand new tablet, I never used it on any previous version.

Comment: The solution is [USB passthrough](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=usb+passthrough+virtualbox). "No servant can serve two masters." If Windows has control of the tablet, Ubuntu cannot control it. If Ubuntu has control, Windows cannot use it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try to read it and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Ok I am slowly moving to make it work. So far the pointer does not work properly, but the writing is very good.
I dont know if it will eventually work perfectly, but your answer is certainly the right one ! I should point out that I had to update my version of virtualbox and install the extension pack to have access to usb features.

Comment: You may not be able to get it working perfectly.  USB passthrough is pretty hit and miss.  I'd consider it a VirtualBox issue.

Comment: Now the tablet seems to be perfectly recognized, the only issue is that the pointer does not move with the pen.
Actually it does move, because when I "blank click" stuff happens, but it works as if there was a second invisible pointer.

Comment: My *guess* is ubuntu is not drawing the pointer, but expects the hardware to control it.  You'd need to enable software pointer.